# I/O error on GET in TestRestTemplate getForEntity method

Tags: java, spring, testing

```
var restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
var actual = restTemplate.getForEntity(new URI("http://localhost:8080/foo"), FooDto.class);
```

When I try to use this method an Exception occurs

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/foo": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: The error means that there is no service listening on localhost:8080. Does the test start the application on port 8080?

Comment: Application starts with testcontainer for test use

Comment: May be `@SpringBootTest` is starting the app on a random port. Do you use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` ?

Comment: Yeah, WebEnviroment.DEFINED_PORT fianlly helped, thanks !

Comment: Glad to help. I transformed the comment to a answer. It may help others.

Answer (score 0):

This exception (Connection refused) means that there is no service listening on the localhost port 8080.

review this:

- Check IP and port.
- Server is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `@SpringBootTest` is configured to use a random port. If it is the case spring-boot will start the app in a random port other than 8080.

Remove the random port config `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` then the app will start on port 8080 (or the port configured by `server.port`)